# finding string in .txt file and delete it

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

i write folder content (files wit .pdf .doc and .xls) in a small txt file. every filename get a new line in the txt file. Works fine.
Now i want to remove all line with the .pdf files.
I still use the following code to remove false entries (fail.png in this case):

```
def clean():
    with open("files.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        with open("files.txt", "w") as f:
            for line in lines:
                if line.strip("\n") != "fail.png":
                    f.write(line)

clean_folderlog()
```

Is it possible to use some sort of "wildcard" (*.pdf) instead of the specific file name?
Or is there a complete other way to solve that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why are you opening the file in read mode and immediately opening in write mode? Cant you do it just once?

Comment: good question. the code growing this way. is it enough to open the file in write mode to read and write from/to the file?

Comment: In general you don't want to read and write at the same time. Why don't you do this filtering at the time of the initial write. I mean, instead of writing all filenames to the file and then removing some, just don't write the bad ones in the first place

Comment: After readlines() you can just close the file, i.e. just unindent the second `with` to top level.

Comment: thanks for all the advices! i am still learning and you all helped a lot with good ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options:

You could check wether the line contains the string '.pdf':

```
if not "pdf" in line.strip("\n")
    f.write(line)
```

You could also use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html). This can be useful in other situations where you want to have a more complex pattern matching.

```
import re

with open("testdata.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if not re.match(".+\.pdf$",line):
            f.write(line)
```

- `.+` matches any character
- `\.` matches the literal dot
- `pdf` matches the literal chars 'pdf'
- `$` matches at the end of the line

Whole code would look like this:

```
def clean():
    with open("files.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open("files.txt", "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if not "pdf" in line.strip("\n"):
                f.write(line)

clean_folderlog()
```

Also, I fixed the indentation, because the write-open doesn't have to be indented

Comment: does not work very well. program failed and i got an empty txt file.

Comment: Oh I forgot a ':' at the end of the if statement

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of options:

- Check if the string *ends* with ".pdf":

  ```
    if not line.endswith(".pdf"):
  ```
- Use the `re` module (most general pattern matching):

  ```
    import re
    ...
    if not re.match(r"\.pdf$", line):
  ```
- Use the `fnmatch` module for shell-style pattern matching:

  ```
    from fnmatch import fnmatch
    ....
    if not fnmatch(line, "*.pdf"):
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily replace your two functions of writing folder content and removing unnecessary files with, for example, such code snippet, written below:

```
import os

extensions = ['.pdf', 'PUT_YOUR_OTHER_EXTENSIONS']

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for file_name in os.listdir('PUT_YOUR_FOLDER_PATH'):
            if os.path.isfile(file_name) and not file_name.endswith(tuple(extensions)):
                f.write("%s\n" % file_name)
```

It will write in a file all filenames of your folder. You just need to put in list extensions that you don't need. Enjoy!

**Note:** This works for one folder, that is mentioned in `os.listdir()` function. For writing all files from subfolders, use recursive walk.